# Which library has a better performance react-native-firebase or firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to implement Firebase with React Native and I am not sure what library I should use, [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) or [react-native-fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase).

I trust more in the official one, firebase, but there is a comparison table which shows that react-native-firebase supports more features than firebase. Which has more features, have a better performance?

Comment: Opinion based question. Please ask this in react-native facebook group or quora

Comment: I changed slightly the question so isn't opinion-based, hope this makes my question clearly. Could the question be open again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) is mainly developed for web and whereas [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) is mainly developed for `React-Native` with the help of `firebase` native sdk. So in the performance wise the [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) will work better than the [Firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) because [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) runs in the native thread so you could get the better frame rate in react native whereas the Firebase-js-sdk runs in the Js thread.

I will recommend you to go ahead with the [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase).

Comment: Any real data or tests here though? I assume react-native-firebase has to go over a bridge with every connection, could actually be slower for small packets?